How to efficiently store varying size byte arrays in an Oracle database?
I have an Oracle database table where I need to store byte array in one of the columns. The size distribution of these byte arrays is as follows:

80% are under 1000 bytes
15% are between 1000 and 2000 bytes
5% are over 2000 bytes

One approach I considered is using two nullable columns, instead of one:

A RAW(2000) column for storing the 95% of byte arrays that are under
2000 bytes
A BLOB column for storing byte arrays larger than 2000 bytes

Is this a good strategy for storing byte arrays in this way, or would it be better to use a single BLOB column? What are the pros and cons of each approach, particularly in terms of performance, storage efficiency, and complexity?

It would be better to use a single BLOB column.  BLOB columns are stored separately from the rest of the row.  The only way to know the pros and cons would be for you to run tests on an Oracle database and publish the results for the rest of us.

@GilbertLeBlanc Thank. From what I've researched, accessing a BLOB column can be more costly compared to a RAW column. But, BLOBs are great for handling variable-sized data (without worrying about size limit). I'm trying to figure out if there's a best practice for this. Ultimately, you’re right that running tests to compare the selected approaches is necessary.

blob access is significantly slower than raw because clients have to make multiple database calls to the LOB interface per row, even for smaller values stored in-row. You can mitigate this at fetch time by querying small values separately from >2K values, and casting small values to raw. That's a similar approach to your raw+ blob idea but the differentiation happens at query time rather than at rest in the table. See below for an example of how to implement this.
Storage efficiency is pretty close either way - if the BLOB is < 2K it can store in-row without consuming an entire chunk (minimum of your database block size, usually 8K, 16K, 32K) so small values don't waste space, but there is a 32 byte overhead in row for LOBs so for very short values raw has an edge of space efficiency. But if most of your values are 500 bytes, a 32 byte overhead isn't a big deal.
Really, neither raw nor blob are intended for arrays, per se, though if the array has fixed width elements you can certainly work with them. An array by definition involves multiple pieces of data, but column values in relational databases are intended (and work best) for single discrete values, not multiple elements. The most straight-forward way to model an array is a child table with one array element per row and a position/sequence column for ordering. This allows much simpler access to or update of a specific array element without having to work with LOBs or substring math - and you can index it to retrieve an array element without having to read the entire array.
Other options that are meant to handle arrays without using a child table include: varray (if on update you would replace the whole thing) and nested table (if you need to update individual array elements separately). A nested table is stored in its own segment but varray will store in-line until 2K and then automatically be stored as a blob, but still accessed like a varray.  One nice thing about a varray is that you work with it like a normal array - access by element index.
If you do stick with blob and want the advantages of non-lob fetching for smaller values, try storing the values in a single blob column in the table, but using SQL within a view to break them out into two columns that you can query:
CREATE VIEW mytable_v
AS
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       CASE WHEN (dbms_lob.getlength(myblob) > 2000) THEN myblob END myblob_blob,
       CAST(CASE WHEN (myblob IS NULL OR dbms_lob.getlength(myblob) <= 2000) THEN myblob END AS raw(2000)) myblob_raw
  FROM mytable

Then query from your client:
SELECT col1,col2,myblob_blob,myblob_raw FROM mytable_v
 

This hides the complexity of breaking the value out into two fetchable columns, while preventing you from having to store them on disk in separate columns and risking datatype overflow and complexity around shifting data from one to the other on update.

Thanks for the detailed response. In our use case, this column is intended to store the payload of a message, and we treat the byte array as a single entity. We never need to access or update individual elements within the byte array. Instead, we always load and update the entire byte array as a whole. Given this requirement, would you still recommend considering other approaches like VARRAY or nested tables, or would sticking with a BLOB or RAW column be more appropriate?

@Arya, A "message" (email, web page text entry, log file contents, etc..) is a single unstructured entity, not an array.  I would use a LOB of some kind. If it is a readable text message, it should be a CLOB, not a BLOB. If however by "message" you mean a machine-readable payload that is actually structured as a real array of individual elements, then use varray.

By "message," I mean various types of events exchanged between two users, so perhaps "event" is a more accurate term. For example, events like "new message," "delete message," "message read," etc., are all stored in this table. Each event has a payload that we serialize using an optimized serialization framework, resulting in a byte array (byte[]) rather than text. We store, retrieve, and update this entire byte array as a whole.
For example, the payload of a "delete message" or "message read" event is much smaller than that of a "new message" event since they don't contain text.

@Arya, you might want to consider using a separate message type column (or even key to a message type table) and using your LOB col only for new message text. You wouldn't want to have to programmatically key off of anything in a LOB column, so you won't want to have to read it just to tell the difference between event types. Try to keep LOBs to unstructured, programmatically meaningless text.

Yes, we have an event_type column that indicates the type of event stored in each row. My idea was to store the payload in either the BLOB or the RAW(2000) column based on only its size, independent of the event_type. This means for each row, one of these columns would be NULL while the other is not.
When retrieving records, we would select both columns and use the non-null one in the application. Now, the key question is whether selecting a BLOB column that contains a NULL value has any performance cost. If there’s no significant overhead, this approach could be suitable

@Arya, I don't believe a NULL BLOB will cost you anything. But you also don't need to store in two different columns. You can store everything in just a BLOB and in your query pull it two different ways (using two SELECT columns in the query block). One would conditionally remain a BLOB CASE WHEN (dbms_lob.getlength > 2000) THEN myblob END, the other would be CAST(CASE WHEN (dbms_lob.getlength(myblob) <= 2000) THEN myblob END AS raw(2000)). That way you get the benefit of non-lob fetching for small values without having to store in two different columns and datatypes on disk.

@Arya, it is always better to do these kinds of tricks in SQL rather than in your table itself. Think of what would happen if you update a value and it changes its length to cross the 2000-byte boundary - do you have the logic to move it to a different column? Such changes also risk datatype overflows in code. I suggest the query method in my previous comment, but coded into a view over the table so that downstream code can simply hit the view and not worry about the complexity itself. I'll edit my answer with an example.
